# How to implement get() recursively

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I was wondering what I am doing wrong with my get method. I've done this before using loops but I cant seem to get the same using recursion. My size() method works with recursion but I am very confused with why I can't seem to get get() to work. Can somebody give me any pointers to whats wrong or if I am just mixing up the positions of the code.

```
public class Node {

    public Node previous;
    public Node next;


    public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    if (next == null) {
        count += 1;
    }
    if (next != null) {
        count = 1 + next.size();
    }
    return count; 
    }


    public Node get(int idx) { 
    int count = 0;
    if (next != null) {
        if (idx >= 0 && idx <= size()) {
            if (count == idx) {
                return next.previous;
            }
            count++;
        }
        //return get(idx);
    }
    return next.previous;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
public Node get(int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        // Asked negative index. Throw exception or return null
    }
    if (index == 0) { return this; }
    if (next == null) {
        // Index out of bounds. Throw exception or return null
    }
    return next.get(index - 1);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like I did it with my `Cell<T> class`. 
Every time you `increment counter` and then invoke `get(idx)` again, `counter` will be reset to `0`. This is because recursion is taking place in the `Stack` and there is only one variable called `counter`.

```
public Cell<T> get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size()) {     // index is out of bonds
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else {
        innerGet(index);
    }

}

public Cell<T> innerGet(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {                       // this element is supposed to be zero
        return this;
    } else {
        return next.innerGet(--index);      // decrement the index
    }
}
```

If you `decrement index` every time you invoke `innerGet(index)` recursively, it works. It is like incrementing a counter, but the other way round.
I implemented `innerGet(int index)` because if you invoke `get(int index)` recursively, this has an O(n^2) because of the `size()` method. It is O(n) if you implement it this way.